# No runtime on my Worklight 6.2 Console

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server, websphere-liberty

After deploying an war file in a Worklight 6.2 environment, the console doesn't show the associated runtime environment : No runtime can be found. It's a basic usage of Worklight 6.2, but I don't know how to fix it !

What I've done :

1. Installation of Worklight Entreprise 6.2 on WebSphere Liberty 8.5.5.2 + DB2 V10.5
2. customisation of the configuration-liberty-db2.xml with my settings
3. ant -f myxmlfile admdatabases
4. ant -f myxmlfile adminstall
5. ant -f myxmlfile databases
6. ant -f myxmlfile install

I have the worklight console in the path ~/worklightconsole but no runtime !
and in the liberty log :

---

[6/24/14 15:28:00:978 CEST] 00000021 com.worklight.common.util.jmx.LibertyRuntimeMBeanHandler     I Bean '*' does not exist.
[6/24/14 15:28:00:979 CEST] 00000021 com.ibm.worklight.admin.services.RuntimeService              I No mxbeans found

[image: Console with no runtime]

And here is an extract of my server.xml liberty file :

ant task for context root '/myapp'. -->

```
<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight project runtime application. -->
<application id="myapp" name="myapp" location="MyProject.war" context-root="/myapp" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/myapp/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Worklight project runtime. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="myapp/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="myapp/publicWorkLightPort" value='"9080"'/>


<!-- Declare the jar files for DB2 access through JDBC. -->
<library id="myapp/DB2Lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/myapp/db2" includes="db2jcc4.jar,db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="myapp/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="myapp/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50001" user="db2inst1" password="db2inst1" currentSchema="WRKLGHT"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server reports database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="myapp/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="myapp/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50001" user="db2inst1" password="db2inst1" currentSchema="WLREPORT"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/myapp'. -->
```

Comment: Where have you located your MyProject.war file?

Comment: MyProject.war is in the apps folder of my Liberty server :
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/servers/server1/apps # ls
appcenterconsole.war  applicationcenter.war  MyProject.war  worklightadmin.war  worklightconsole.war

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a defect in the Liberty 8.5.5.2 classloader that can affect Worklight (not only the 6.2 version but all versions) and even existing non Worklight applications that define classloading policy rule in the server.xml file.
The workaround is to delete the content of the Liberty server workarea directory and start the server with the --clean option  (each time you restart also).

Comment: The workaround doesn't work, but point the fact I used the IBM JAVA SDK 7.1. Changing that to IBM JAVA SDK 6 solved the issue.

Comment: @Aymeric I also changed to use IBM JDK 1.6, but still no runtime even if I run with a blank workspace (only default server defined by worklight studio, or after I created blank app 'a' and 'run on worklight deployment server'), I even see 'JMXConnector' war shown in console logs.