# No runtime on my Worklight 6.2 Console after installing analytics

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I just installed Worklight 6.2 server, use the configuration tool to deploy a simple project and it works OK. Then I followed the instructions in knowledge center to install analytics. Afterwards, when I open WL console in the browser, I got "No runtime can be found." Analytics seems to work fine

My war file is in Liberty apps folder. in my case C:\IBM\WebSphere\Liberty\usr\servers\simpleServer\apps

I have tried the solution below, but didn't work. I removed the files in workarea and checked for my jdk, which is jdk6_45
[No runtime on my Worklight 6.2 Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391804/no-runtime-on-my-worklight-6-2-console)

Here's my server.xml

```
<!-- Enable features -->
<featureManager>
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>

    <!-- Begin for analytics -->
    <feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End for analytics -->

    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight installer. -->
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight installer. -->


    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature> -->
    <feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


    <!-- Begin of features added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/worklight'. -->
    <feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
    <feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
    <feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
    <feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
    <!-- End of features added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/worklight'. -->

</featureManager>

<httpEndpoint id="defaultHttpEndpoint"
              host="*"
              httpPort="9080"
              httpsPort="9443" >

    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight installer. -->
    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->
    <!-- Option soReuseAddr added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/worklight'. -->
    <tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

</httpEndpoint>

<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight installer. -->

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Console application. -->
<application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <group name="appcentergroup"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Services application. -->
<application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <group name="appcentergroup"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the user registry for the IBM Application Center. -->
<basicRegistry id="applicationcenter-registry" realm="ApplicationCenter">
    <!--    Worklight user.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <user name="WorklightRESTUser" password="WGFtAaW8fTma"/>

    <!-- The users defined here are members of group "appcentergroup",
         thus have role "appcenteradmin", and can therefore perform
         administrative tasks through the IBM Application Center Console. -->
    <user name="appcenteradmin" password="admin"/>

    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
    <group name="appcentergroup">
        <member name="appcenteradmin"/>
        <member name="demo"/>
    </group>
</basicRegistry>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Application Center. -->

<!-- Define the AppCenter services endpoint in order for the AppCenter console to be able to invoke the REST service.
        You need to enable this property if the server is behind a reverse proxy
        or if the context root of the Application Center Services application is different from '/applicationcenter'. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.services.endpoint" value='"http://proxyhost:proxyport/applicationcenter"'/> -->
<!-- The directory with binaries of the 'aapt' program, from the Android SDK's platform-tools package. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="android.aapt.dir" value='"C:/IBM/Worklight/ApplicationCenter/tools/android-sdk"'/>
<!-- The protocol of the application resources URI. This property is optional. It is only needed if the protocol of the external and internal URI are different. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.protocol" value='"http"'/> -->
<!-- The hostname of the application resources URI. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.host" value='"proxyhost"'/> -->
<!-- The port of the application resources URI. This property is optional. -->
<!-- <jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.proxy.port" value="proxyport"/> -->

<!-- Declare the jar files for DB2 access through JDBC. -->
<library id="DB2Lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/db2" includes="*.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/AppCenterDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="APPCNTR" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000" user="db2admin" password="db2admin"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight installer. -->
```

Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    This configuration is the minimum one that you need to create an SSL configuration.
    With this configuration, the Liberty server creates the keystore and the certificate, 
    if it does not exist yet, during the SSL initialization.
    The created certificate is a self-signed certificate that is valid for 365 days.
    Do not use the certificates that the Liberty server created for production use.
    For more information see  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_sec_ssl.html
-->

```
<administrator-role>
    <!--    Worklight JMX User.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
    -->
    <user>WorklightRESTUser</user>

</administrator-role>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="9443"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="WorklightRESTUser"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="WGFtAaW8fTma"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value="Liberty"/>
<!--    Worklight JNDI property for JMX connection.
    [Added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> Ant task for context root '/wladmin'] 
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone"/>

<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->

<!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Service application. -->
<application id="wladmin" name="wladmin" location="worklightadmin.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="demo"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary>

            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare web container custom properties for the Worklight Administration Service application. -->
<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Service. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="wladmin/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"Hello_Worklight_Server"'/>


<!-- Declare the jar files for DB2 access through JDBC. -->
<library id="wladmin/DB2Lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/wladmin/db2" includes="db2jcc4.jar,db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Administration database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="wladmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="wladmin/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000" user="db2admin" password="db2admin" currentSchema="WLADMIN"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the Worklight Administration Console application. -->
<application id="worklightconsole" name="worklightconsole" location="worklightconsole.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="demo"/>

        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
        </security-role>

        <security-role name="worklightoperator">
        </security-role>

    </application-bnd>

</application>

<!-- Declare web container custom properties for the Worklight Administration Console application. -->
<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false" deferServletLoad="false"/>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the Worklight Administration Console. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklightconsole/ibm.worklight.admin.endpoint" value='"*://*:*/wladmin"'/>


<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <installWorklightAdmin> ant task for context root '/wladmin'. -->


<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/worklight'. -->

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight project runtime application. -->
<application id="worklight" name="worklight" location="HelloWorklight.war" type="war">
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/lib" includes="worklight-jee-library.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>

<!-- Declare the JNDI properties for the IBM Worklight project runtime. -->
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='"http"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/publicWorkLightPort" value='"9080"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="worklight/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='"Hello_Worklight_Server"'/>


<!-- Declare the jar files for DB2 access through JDBC. -->
<library id="worklight/DB2Lib">
    <fileset dir="${shared.resource.dir}/worklight/db2" includes="db2jcc4.jar,db2jcc_license_cu.jar"/>
</library>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000" user="db2admin" password="db2admin" currentSchema="WRKLGHT"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- Declare the IBM Worklight Server reports database. -->
<dataSource jndiName="worklight/jdbc/WorklightReportsDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="worklight/DB2Lib"/>
    <properties.db2.jcc databaseName="WRKLGHT" serverName="localhost" portNumber="50000" user="db2admin" password="db2admin" currentSchema="WLREPORT"/>
</dataSource>

<!-- For analytics -->
<application context-root="/analytics"
     id="analytics"
     location="analytics.war"
     name="analytics"
     type="war">
</application>

<!-- End of configuration added by IBM Worklight <configureApplicationServer> ant task for context root '/worklight'. -->
```

Answer (score 2):

Worklight still needs the restConnector-1.0 feature in Liberty so you shouldn't comment it out. The analytics delivered in 6.2 cannot run when the restConnector feature is present. You have two options:

**Option 1 -** Download the latest iFix. The latest iFix comes with a version of analytics that can run with the restConnector feature. You will have to add the 'parentLast' classloader declaration to analytics entry in server.xml. Example:

> ```
> < application context-root="/analytics" id="analytics"location="analytics.war" name="analytics" type="war">
>        < classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
>      </ application>
> ```

**Option 2 -** Install the analytics on a separate liberty server (recommended approach for a production server)

Documentation for the above will be updated in the next fixpack.

As a side note, are you sure that the 'no runtime' error is related to analytics and not just a coincidence? Does the error still occur when you remove analytics and reverse the steps you did for installation?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As soon as I uncomment out the restConnector-1.0 feature in server.xml, worklight console works. However, now I am getting context root not found for analytics. I am planning to try option 1 and will post an update.

Comment: I applied 6.2.0.0-WL-Server-IF201407191643 using Installation Manager (update). Worklight console is fine, but I got Context Root not found when I try to open analytics on my browser. Then I add the 'parentLast' classloader in server.xml and both Worklight Console and Analytics are broken (This webpage is not available). If I remove the 'parentLast' classloader, Worklight Console is fine, but again Analytics shows Context Root not found

Comment: <application context-root="/analytics" 
  id="analytics" 
  location="analytics.war" 
  name="analytics" 
  type="war">
  < classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
</application>

Comment: Just noticed there is an extra space in from of "< classloader" after fixing it, back to Worklight Console OK, Context Root Not Found for Analytics Console <application context-root="/analytics" 
  id="analytics" 
  location="analytics.war" 
  name="analytics" 
  type="war">
  <classloader delegation="parentLast"/>
    </application>

Comment: Commented out <feature>restConnector-1.0</feature> now back to the original problem where Analytics Console works but No Runtime on Worklight Console. Did I apply the wrong ifix?

Comment: You should leave the restConnector feature there. After you applied the fix, did you remember to replace the existing analytics WAR file with the new WAR that came with the fix?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out. I forgot to do that. Once I replace the analytics WAR, everything works fine