# WLP :: Worklight :: Can't install runtime

Tags: worklight-server, websphere-liberty, worklight-runtime

I'm using Worklight 6.2 server edition and I can't deploy a working runtime (of other environments) on my server.

I'm using webpshere liberty profile v8.5.5 and when I deploy the runtime via GUI it says success and on server.xml I can see the new configuration for the app.

However when I go to the worklightconsole I don't see my runtime to upload the app.

On messages.log there is a error regarding JMX connection.
The quoted error is

```
Failed to obtain JMX connection to access an MBean. There might be a JMX configuration error: No JMX connector is configured
```

I'm refering this because I've seen some post on SO saying that these issues might be connected. However I have the restConnector-1.0 on my WLP features.
Reference: [No runtime on my Worklight 6.2 Console after installing analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028361/no-runtime-on-my-worklight-6-2-console-after-installing-analytics)

On messages.log there is some other things that I found interesting, like the correct start of the runtime I've deployed

```
[11/12/14 5:50:45:177 CST] 00000012 com.worklight.server.bundle.project.JeeProjectActivator          I FWLST0002I: ========= Project /HelloWorld started. The project WAR file version is     6.2.0.00.20140922-2259,running on server version 6.2.0.00.20140613-0730. [project HelloWorld]
```

and two erros while starting my server

```
[11/12/14 5:50:49:911 CST] 00000012 SystemErr                                                    R 24  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/opt/IBM/WebSphere/Liberty/usr/shared/resources/worklight/lib/worklight-jee-library.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
```

Second error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Timeout while waiting for the management service to start up
```

I don't know what these are but I think it might be related to my problem and this errors eventually appear when I start my server.

Does anyone have any tips for troubleshooting this issue?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: RE: the message about the JMX connection, do you have SSL configured (you need both the https port and a keystore element)? Is the https port able to bind properly?

Comment: I have a httpEndpoint with its https port but I haven't configured it properly. I don't have a ssl certificate yet.

Comment: For at least testing purposes, just add a keystore element that defines a password. Liberty will generate a self-signed cert that is perfectly ok for dev/test.  Minimally, that is: 
   <keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="yourPassword" />

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue from Websphere.

There is a APAR to fix that, a workaround is to restart the server with the --clean option to force a refresh onto the shared libraries.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PI17830