# Worklight 6.2 cannot find runtime when opening Worklight Console

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

I am running a Mac with OS 10.9.4 with Eclipse Standard/SDK, Version: Kepler Service Release 2, Build id: 20140224-0627.

I have installed Worklight 6.2.0.0 and cannot get the Worklight Console to work -- I continually get a "No runtime can be found."

I found this post:
[No runtime on my Worklight 6.2 Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24391804/no-runtime-on-my-worklight-6-2-console) -- but I cannot locate an IBM Java SDK 6 which says it the answer to fix this issue.

I have uninstalled Eclipse, Worklight, Liberty, etc. and started with a fresh install, but I still get the error.

Here is my server.xml file:

```
<server description="worklight">

   <featureManager>
<feature>servlet-3.0</feature>
<feature>jndi-1.0</feature>
<feature>jdbc-4.0</feature>
<feature>restConnector-1.0</feature>
<feature>jsp-2.2</feature>
<feature>appSecurity-1.0</feature>
<feature>ssl-1.0</feature>
<!--
    <feature>appSecurity-2.0</feature>
    <feature>ldapRegistry-3.0</feature>
-->
    <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
</featureManager>

<webContainer invokeFlushAfterService="false"/>
<webContainer com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.suppressLoggingServiceRuntimeExcep="true"/>
<webContainer deferServletLoad="false"/>

<!-- non standard ports were used to avoid future collision with other WebSphere products. -->
<httpEndpoint host="*" httpPort="10080" httpsPort="10443" id="defaultHttpEndpoint">
<tcpOptions soReuseAddr="true"/>

</httpEndpoint>

<!--  change Worklight server side logging: 
  change consoleLogLevel to INFO to see Worklight JavaScript Logger API output
  (for example: in Worklight Adapters).
-->
<logging consoleLogLevel="AUDIT" copySystemStreams="false"/>

<!-- enable next element for Worklight Server traces. 
     change traceSpecification to enable fine grain printing to trace.log file. 
<logging traceSpecification="com.worklight.*=debug=enabled"/>
-->

<applicationMonitor updateTrigger="mbean"/>

<administrator-role>
   <user>admin</user>
</administrator-role>
<keyStore id="defaultKeyStore" password="worklight"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.host" value="localhost"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.port" value="10443"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.platform" value="Liberty"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.topology.clustermode" value="Standalone"/>


<!--
Worklight Console settings START ...
-->
<basicRegistry id="worklight" realm="worklightRealm">
    <user name="demo" password="demo"/>
    <user name="monitor" password="demo"/>
    <user name="deployer" password="demo"/>
    <user name="operator" password="demo"/>
    <user name="admin" password="admin"/>
</basicRegistry>
<!--
JMX admin user JNDI entries
-->
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.user" value="admin"/>

<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.worklight.admin.jmx.pwd" value="admin"/>
<!--
Disabling security integration
-->
<httpSession securityIntegrationEnabled="false"/>
<!--
Declare the IBM Worklight Admin Services application.
-->
<application context-root="worklightadmin" id="worklight-management-service" location="worklight-management-service.war" name="WorklightServices" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="admin"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            <user name="deployer"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            <user name="monitor"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            <user name="operator"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <privateLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil*.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
<!--
Declare the IBM Worklight Admin Console application.
-->
<application context-root="worklightconsole" id="worklight-management-ui" location="worklight-management-ui.war" name="WorklightConsole" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="worklightadmin">
            <user name="admin"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightdeployer">
            <user name="deployer"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightmonitor">
            <user name="monitor"/>
        </security-role>
            <security-role name="worklightoperator">
            <user name="operator"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>

<library id="DerbyLib">
    <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources/derby" includes="derby.jar"/>
</library>
<!--
Declare the IBM Worklight Console admin database.
-->
<dataSource jndiName="worklightadmin/jdbc/WorklightAdminDS" transactional="false">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="DerbyLib"/>
    <properties.derby.embedded createDatabase="create" databaseName="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources/derbyDB/WLADMIN" user="WLADMINISTRATOR"/>
</dataSource>
<!--
... Worklight Console settings END
--></server>
```

When I build the project, here is what the console log says:

```
[2014-08-04 12:34:12] FWLPL0010W: The current server configuration is set to "localhost". 
Therefore the Worklight build uses the primary IP address of this computer (192.168.0.68) instead.
It is recommended to set the server configuration to use the fully qualified hostname or IP address of this computer.
To configure the setting, in the "Servers" view double-click the Worklight Development Server entry and edit the "Host name" field.
[2014-08-04 12:34:53]             Starting build process: application 'GAPPortfolioApp', all environments 
[2014-08-04 12:34:54]             Application 'GAPPortfolioApp' with all environments build finished.
```

Here is what the console log says when opening the Worklight Console:

```
objc[10730]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_55.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 10777
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.1/wlp-1.0.4.cl50120131011-1639) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_55-b13 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[fd00:0:0:0:3e15:c2ff:fec6:5116]:10080/IBMJMXConnectorREST/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[fd00:0:0:0:3e15:c2ff:fec6:5116]:10080/worklightadmin/
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.core.Context annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.PathParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.MatrixParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.CookieParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.QueryParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[WARNING ] CWNEN0070W: The javax.ws.rs.HeaderParam annotation class will not be recognized because it was loaded from the null location rather than from a product class loader.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightServices started in 5.208 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://[fd00:0:0:0:3e15:c2ff:fec6:5116]:10080/worklightconsole/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application WorklightConsole started in 0.283 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

Is there a mismatch with Eclipse and Worklight or Eclipse and Liberty that I may be missing?

I would appreciate any help with this!

Thanks!

Comment: Oracle Java 6 should do just fine as well.

Comment: All of your output looks fine.  This "No Runtime" screen displays when no app has been deployed. Did you deploy an app to the Worklight Server via right clicking on the app > Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server?  If you do that, you should see something in your console log such as:

Starting build process: application 'wlapp', all environments 
Application 'wlapp' with all environments build finished.
Deploying application 'wlapp' with all environments to Worklight Server... 
Application 'wlapp' deployed successfully with all environments

Comment: I performed the Run As... > 1. Run On Worklight Development Server on the app folder (the folder name of the app under the "apps" folder). I think selected the topmost folder, right-clicked and selected "Open Worklight Console" which opened in Firefox and the console appeared.  However, the only link I have is "Preview as Common Resources" which does nothing.  I tried to change the URL (http://192.168.0.68:10080/[myProjectName]/apps/services/preview/[myProjectName]/common/0/default/index.html) to the correct index.html, but it does not work.

Comment: To fix, I uninstalled everything and downloaded and installed Eclipse Luna.  Worklight is now working correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix, I uninstalled everything and downloaded and installed Eclipse Luna. Worklight is now working correctly.